# How can I get the first registry with a type A and the first registry with a type B and move it to a single row

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata, databricks

I am trying to use python and pandas to get the first registry with the type A or B and the first registry with the type C or D and move that to a single row. I want this per Id.

Will be easy for me to demonstrate with this sample case

`Id,type,Datetime
1, A, 2018-01-01
1, I, 2018-01-02
1, I, 2018-01-03
1, C, 2018-01-04
2, I, 2018-01-01
2, B, 2018-01-02
2, J, 2018-01-03
2, K, 2018-01-04
2, D, 2018-01-05
2, C, 2018-01-06
3, A, 2018-01-03
3, D, 2018-01-09
4, A, 2018-01-03
4, D, 2018-01-05
4, C, 2018-01-04`

I wanted the result of the processing to be

`Id, ProcessEvent, ProcessDate, DispatchedEvent, DispatchedDate
1, A, 2018-01-01, C, 2018-01-04
2, B, 2018-01-01, D, 2018-01-05
3, A, 2018-01-03, D, 2018-01-09
4, A, 2018-01-03, C, 2018-01-04`

I am currently trying to do this using python and pandas in a Databricks cluster but I am opening to Other ideas I need to to that in files that come up to a total of few TB so it is a large dataset so speed must be in mind and I can't store the whole dataset in memory.

Comment: What if the `C` row is before the `A` row? Do you want this per id?

Comment: The way this data it is structured there is no chance of the c row be before the A row but if it is I would still get the time of A or B and the time of C. Doesn't matter if C is before A or B

Comment: I want this per Id.

Comment: Sorry, so how is possible distinguish which `Id` have type `A,C` and which `B,D` ? Maybe help add another `Id` with output?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the Id has A,C or B,D or A,D or B,C I want the first A or B and the first C or D. Added another example Id 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) per column `Id`, set to index and `rename` columns names:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
df = df.sort_values(['Id','Datetime'])

df1 = (df[df['type'].isin(['A','B'])]
          .drop_duplicates('Id')
          .set_index('Id')
          .rename(columns={'type':'ProcessEvent','Datetime':'ProcessDate'}))
df2 = (df[df['type'].isin(['C','D'])]
          .drop_duplicates('Id')
          .set_index('Id')
          .rename(columns={'type':'DispatchedEvent','Datetime':'DispatchedDate'}))
```

Last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   Id ProcessEvent ProcessDate DispatchedEvent DispatchedDate
0   1            A  2018-01-01               C     2018-01-04
1   2            B  2018-01-02               D     2018-01-05
2   3            A  2018-01-03               D     2018-01-09
3   4            A  2018-01-03               C     2018-01-04
```

Comment: Does this works with the case of C being before D in the file but with the earlier Date?

For example
```
Id,type,Datetime
4, A, 2018-01-01
4, C, 2018-01-03
4, D, 2018-01-02
```
would that generate
4,A,2018-01-0,D,2018-01-02

in case not I can just add one order by date before.

Comment: @GabrielMonteiroNepomuceno - Can you change sample data? Maybe sorting is necessary first.

Comment: Corrected the sample data.

Comment: @GabrielMonteiroNepomuceno - First convert to datetime and sorting by columns Id and Datetime, check edited answer.